# Не загружается изображенияе в Firebase Storage

Tags: android, firebase

Ребята,проблема следующая. 
У меня есть Fragment. В этом фрагменте я хочу загрузить изображение и после его отобразить на экране. Пока реализовал только загрузку, но почему-то у меня выбивает ошибку.
Ошибка ссылается на эту строчку кода:

```
file.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
```

Вот весь код:

```
public class EditProfile extends Fragment{
    private static final int GALLERY_INTENT=2;
    private EditText editProfileName;
    private EditText editProfilePhone;
    private EditText editProfileNick;
    private ImageView image;
    private Button saveBtn;
    int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 111;
    private final int LENGTH = 1000;
    FirebaseUser user;

    public EditProfile() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_edit_profile, container, false);
        image=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.edit_profile_photo);
        user= FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        editProfileName=(EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.edit_profile_name);
        editProfilePhone=(EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.edit_profile_phone);
        saveBtn=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.edit_profile_save);

        saveBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                chageProfile();
            }
        });
        image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setImage();
            }
        });
        return v;
    }

    public void setImage(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);

        intent.setType("image/*");

        startActivityForResult(intent,GALLERY_INTENT); 
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode==GALLERY_INTENT && resultCode==RESULT_OK){
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            StorageReference storageReference=FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
            StorageReference file=storageReference.child(user.getUid()).child(uri.getLastPathSegment());
            file.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Upload Done",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Ошибки:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                   Process: by.ittech.test_chat, PID: 6769
                                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=65538, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://media/external/images/media/34 }} to activity {by.ittech.test_chat/by.ittech.test_chat.MainActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/images/media/34 from pid=6769, uid=10060 requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3699)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3742)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1393)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/images/media/34 from pid=6769, uid=10060 requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
                                                                       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1599)
                                                                       at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:183)
                                                                       at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionWithFileNotFoundExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:146)
                                                                       at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.openTypedAssetFile(ContentProviderNative.java:692)
                                                                       at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1104)
                                                                       at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:942)
                                                                       at android.content.ContentResolver.openFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:795)
                                                                       at android.content.ContentResolver.openFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:749)
                                                                       at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                                       at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference.putFile(Unknown Source)
                                                                       at by.ittech.test_chat.EditProfile.onActivityResult(EditProfile.java:99)
                                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onActivityResult(FragmentActivity.java:164)
                                                                       at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6428)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3695)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3742) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1393) 
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Изменил 
StorageReference file=storageReference.child(user.getUid()).child(uri.getLastPathSegment())
на
 StorageReference file=storageReference.child("images/photo.jpg");
Помогло.